# Loop through .fig files and group them into folders based on the file name

Tags: matlab

I have a lot of .fig files that are named like this: `20160922_01_id_32509055.fig`, `20160921_02_id_53109418.fig` and so on.

So I thought that I create a script that loop through all the .fig files in the folder and group(copy) them into another folder(s) based on the last number in the file name. The folder is created based on the id number. Is this possible?

I have been looking on other solutions involving looping through folders but I am totally fresh. This would make it easier for me to check the .fig files while I am learning to do other stuff in Matlab.

Comment: the first "number" is obviously a date ... wouldn't it make much more sense to group them by date??

Comment: I thought so too, but they are so many and in the end I don't really care about the date but the ID. But thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is possible with MATLAB! We can use `dir` to get all .fig files, then use `regexp` to get the numeric part of each filename and then use `copyfile` to copy the file to it's new home. If you want to move it instead, you can use `movefile` instead .

```
% Define where the files are now and where you want them.
srcdir = '/my/input/directory';
outdir = '/my/output/directory';

% Find all .fig files in the source directory
figfiles = dir(fullfile(srcdir, '*.fig'));
figfiles = {figfiles.name};

for k = 1:numel(figfiles)
    % Extract the last numeric part from the filename
    numpart = regexp(figfiles{k}, '(?<=id_)\d+', 'match', 'once');

    % Determine the folder we are going to put it in
    destination = fullfile(outdir, numpart);

    % Make sure the folder exists
    if ~exist(destination, 'dir')
        mkdir(destination)
    end

    % Copy the file there!
    copyfile(fullfile(srcdir, figfiles{k}), destination)
end
```

Comment: Awesome, MATLAB seems to be really nice, I will try it out later today and tell how it went, I really appreciate your help. Btw, in a later stage I want to compare ID's that are the same with a difference of lets say + or - 1000. Can this be added somewhere after "?<=id"?

Comment: @HumbleMan Well so `numpart` is a string that represents that number so you can convert it to a number using `str2double` and then do whatever comparison you want. You'll have to try it out. Also some would argue (including me) that this sort of file manipulation is one of MATLAB's weakest points.

Comment: Could you help me a little bit more, how would I allow to make the id's differ by 10%? This means that if the one id is 10% less or more than another id, it would pass and would be copied.

Comment: I tried the script btw, and it is working! The only thing is that it creates folders for these .fig files that id only exists once as well, making a lot of folders. Is it possible to tweak the code so it only creates a folder if it finds at least two .fig files with the same id? :)

Comment: @HumbleMan The 10% thing is a little vague because you could have one ID that is within 10% of two other ids (one higher one lower). You would really need to specify a range of id's for each folder.

Comment: The point of our answers isn't to write a completely custom script for you, but rather to point you in the right direction. You should be able to take the information here and play with it to get exactly what you want. If you have a specific question about why your changes aren't working, then open a new question about that question rather than continuously changing this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example how to identify and copy the files. I'll let you do the for loop :)

```
>> Figs = dir('*.fig');    % I had two .fig files on my desktop
>> Basename = strsplit(Figs(1).name, '.'); 
>> Id = strsplit(Basename{1}, '_');
>> Id = Id{3};
>> mkdir(fullfile('./',Id));
>> copyfile(Figs(1).name, fullfile('./',Id));
```

Play with the commands to see what they do. It should be straightforward :)